# How do I map my database tables in Azure Durable Function properly?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Orchestration in Azure Durable Functions, and the code has been tested and it's logic checks out, however, I don't know how to properly map my database tables to my entities model.

I have built an ORM using sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL, and I use a custom method called `start_mappers()` to map my database metadata to my Entities inside every Activity.

What is the recommended way to map these tables inside a Durable Function?

My code starts the following way, using `Function Chaining` at first and then `Fan-In/Fan-Out` patterns, and attempting to map the database in every activity.

```
def an_orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
  
  input_= context.get_input()
  
  limit= input_['limit']

  ta= input_['ta']
  
  # Function Chaining:

  activity_one= yield context.call_activity(
    name= 'GetSomeDataFromADataBase',
    input_= {
      'limit': limit,
      'ta': ta
    }
  )

  # ...
```

```
def main(ActivityInput):
  
  start_mappers()

  # do something...
```

Should I map my database in my Starter Function? Or in my Orchestrator somehow? Or are these practices not recommended and I should use another approach?

I'm fairly confused as how to proceed in this case, specially since I'm still learning a lot about Azure Functions and their behaviour.

I have tried mapping it once on the main execution script for the Orchestrator, but it complains that the database tables are not mapped when I try executing an Activity if I do that, so I use a try/except block to attempt mapping, which is pretty clear that it's not the best approach.

I have also tried to find a solution to this but couldn't find it anywhere, and would really appreciate some clarity on this.